# sql server select where breaks with field containing apostrophe

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have set up a job to run reports and uses multiple tables with joins. I am joining two tables on a string field and if the field contains an apostrophe, it does not return any matches. This is weird and not sure why is is happening now and never before. I am perhaps not identifying the exact cause but will appreciate any help here:

Example query:    "today's deals"

```
SET @TITLE = (SELECT MAX(B.DATEADDED) as 'td','',
     (C.CLIENT + CHAR(10) +  B.CLIENTKEY)    as 'td','', 
      B.BADQ as 'td','',A.FULLQ as 'td','', B.BADERROR as 'td', 
'' 
FROM BADQUERY AS B 
LEFT JOIN QDATA AS A ON B.BADQ = A.QUERYT 
LEFT JOIN Clients AS C ON C.clientKey = B.clientKey 
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,CAST(B.DATEADDED as datetime),GETDATE())<=420 AND 
      DAY(GETDATE()) = DAY(B.DATEADDED)
GROUP BY B.BADT,A.FULLQ, B.CLIENTKEY,C.CLIENT, B.BADERROR
FOR XML PATH ('tr'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)
```

For some reason A.FULLQ is being returned as NULL. When I do it separately with just a query the result set is also null but I know the matching record in QDATA as A is in the table. So if it is the query with apostrophe how can get the matching field or is sql server matching the data and something else is wrong.

If I try and match with a like it returns results but this is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If `B.BADQ` and  `A.QUERYT` don't exactly match, you won't get any records back.  The fact that it works with a LIKE makes me wonder whether one of them has additional characters, either before or after the matching data (depending on how you set up the LIKE).

Michael Green is right, below, that trailing blanks by themselves don't prevent a match, but, depending on where your data originates, you might have some other character (such as an embedded `CHAR(0)` or a `TAB` character) that doesn't appear when you view the data in the record but which is enough to prevent the records from matching.  You might use the `CHECKSUM()` function on the two strings to verify that they do represent the same data.

Another, similar possibility is that if there is a string of blanks in the values (something like "A, B, '  '") the number of blanks might be different between the two instances.  They'd look the same in HTML (which it looks like you're generating) but they'd be different in reality and be enough to prevent a match.

Finally, the fact that you're generating XML and observing trouble with apostrophes made me think of this:  if the content of an XML tag has an apostrophe, it will be converted to `&apos;`.  That ought to affect only the output, not the functioning, of the query, but I don't know what your data actually looks like.

Comment: Weird thing about the SQL standard - trailing spaces don't count on compare: `declare @a varchar(20) = 'a   ';
declare @b varchar(20) = 'a';

if @a = @b
 print 'equal'
else
 print 'no';`

Comment: Try it without the `FOR XML` clause; the `&apos;` thing was my first thought, too.

Comment: @MichaelGreen You're right. I was remembering incorrectly.  I've certainly been bit by trailing blanks, but it was probably in C#, not SQL!